# Google Voice & Hangouts, what is the deal?

Tags: google-voice

Keep hearing [news about how Google Voice is being merged into Hangouts](http://techcrunch.com/2014/03/18/google-tipped-to-consolidate-communication-by-killing-google-voice-rolling-features-into-hangouts/), but haven't not been able to find anything official about what the impact will be for current Google Voice accounts. Has Google release as plan for what will happen?

Comment: Could you add links to some of those news stories?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal: Good point, added the link, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TechCrunch story you are linking to](http://techcrunch.com/2014/03/18/google-tipped-to-consolidate-communication-by-killing-google-voice-rolling-features-into-hangouts/) refers to [a sole source, namely 9to5google.com](http://9to5google.com/2014/03/18/google-plans-kill-google-voice-in-months-integrate-features-into-hangouts/). That one is a rumour site, which sometimes have good sources, some times not.

In this case, the phrases they use:

> *We’ve heard that* Google Voice is getting dragged to the trash [...]
>   *No specific timing* on the Google Voice migration was given [...]
>   [...] *we’re hearing* the full shuttering and depreciation of the app is the next step [...]

<sup>(my emphasis)</sup>
are just as vague as other rumours which have proved not to materialize. Note that 9to5google.com does not list any sources for this information.

As far as I can see, there's no official word from Google on wether they are planning to merge Google Voice with Google Hangouts. If the rumours materialize, I'm sure Google will provide information on what Google Voice users need to do, if anything.